# UIScrollView Vertical Scrolling when touching inside a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have implemented a scrollview, which holds multiple copies of a custom view.  The custom views contain a UIPanGestureRecoginixer that I use to swipe them to the left (to delete them). When I attempt to scroll vertically, scrolling doesn't occur if I'm touching inside of the CustomView.  However if I set up the subViews and the scrollviews content size so that it scrolls horizontally this issue doesn't occur.  How can I force the scrollview to scroll horizontally even if I'm touching inside of a subview?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the UIPanGestureRecoginzer's delegate and implement

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

It requires you to return a BOOL value. When you return YES, the otherGestureRecognizer will be recognized simultaneous.